# Find keys for values that appear more than once

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
mydict ={1:'apple',2:'banana',3:'banana',4:'apple',5:'mango'}
```

I want to compute a list that contains all the keys for values that appear more than once:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
```

Value `'mango'` only appears once, and therefore key `5` is not present in `mylist`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want `mydict.keys()`?

Comment: Or, to get a real list in Python 3, `list(mydict)`?

Comment: I think he wants the keys for all values that appear more than once. `'mango'` appears only once, and key `5` is not present.

Comment: yes i want that only.al the keys that has same values like 2 and 3 has same value.1 and 4 same value

Comment: It would be best if you could keep track of that while you're creating `mydict`, as dictionaries are optimized (in terms of both performance and ease of use) for key lookup, not value lookup.

Comment: @minitech Hey, I don't know that can get all keys in a dict :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - mind if we roll back or update those edits? I had already made a bunch of changes that your edit overrode (we must have been editing at the same time).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter 
>>> c = Counter(mydict.values())
>>> [k for k, v in mydict.items() if c[v] > 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

On python 2.7, simple way for small dict. Better solution, use collections.Counter.

```
>>> [k for k, v in mydict.items() if mydict.values().count(v) > 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: The only problem with that is that it's computing the `count` for each value every time it sees it.

Comment: Well, it raise `AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'count'` on Python 3.5(does this matter?)

Comment: Well, use a counter maybe. Maybe this should be a comments. Work fine on python 2.7

Comment: Okay, I've just test this on Python 2.7 and it works.